# element.click() on selenium not working (noob needs help)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can a noob get some help here?

Hello guys, this is my first time using python, so bear that in mind.

I'm using selenium to navigate and automatically fill a form on this webpage:

https://sede.administracionespublicas.gob.es/icpco/index.html

is all good except for the last element.click()

**Here is the code so far:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://sede.administracionespublicas.gob.es/icpco/index.html")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

dropdownmenu=driver.find_element_by_id("form")
sel=Select(dropdownmenu)

sel.select_by_visible_text("Málaga")

element=driver.find_element_by_id("btnAceptar")
element.click()

dropdownmenu1=driver.find_element_by_id("tramiteGrupo[0]")
sel=Select(dropdownmenu1)

sel.select_by_value("4067")

element=driver.find_element_by_id("btnAceptar")

element.click()

element=driver.find_element_by_id("btnEntrar")

element.click()

element=driver.find_element_by_id("txtIdCitado")
element.send_keys("Y7356001V")

element=driver.find_element_by_id("txtDesCitado")
element.send_keys("Franco Padron Chirinos")

element=driver.find_element_by_id("txtAnnoCitado")
element.send_keys("1985")

dropdownmenu=driver.find_element_by_id("txtPaisNac")
sel=Select(dropdownmenu)

sel.select_by_visible_text("VENEZUELA")

element=driver.find_element_by_id("btnEnviar")
element.click()

element=driver.find_element_by_id("btnEnviar")
element.click()
```

The problem is the last two rows it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure that finds the element but it doesn't activate the click.

Maaaaybe someone can run the script and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

**Thank you!!!!!**

Comment: Remember that you're getting different pages loaded here.  Your `btnAceptar` and `btnEntrar` and `btnEnviar` clicks are all triggering a new page, and that takes time.  You need to experiment with delays after you press the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a wait before clicking the element. For example, instead of:

```
element=driver.find_element_by_id("btnEnviar")
element.click()
```

Try

```
enviar=driver.find_element_by_id("btnEnviar")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(enviar))
enviar.click()
```

And you will need to import the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```